# SQL Loop form between two days with ID

Tags: sql-server

I Want to create loop between two days and USERID
For Example
If I Choose between 01-01-2017 and 05-01-2017
procedure already insert into my table days between for each user
every single user has a same days

I've tried the following

```
DECLARE @USERID int,@S_Date date,@E_Date date
SELECT @S_Date = @S_Date, @USERID = @USERID
While @S_Date <= @E_Date
begin
    select @S_Date, @USERID
    while @USERID < 3 
    begin
    INSERT INTO myTable values(@S_Date, @USERID)
        select @S_Date as S, @USERID as U
        set @USERID = @USERID + 1

    end
    set @S_Date = DateAdd(Day, 1, @S_Date)
end
```

Comment: Better suited using a recursive CTE and avoid the loop. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824831/generate-dates-between-date-ranges

Comment: @xQbert Recursive cte is much slower than set based approaches as the range generated increases.[Generate a set or sequence without loops - 2 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)

Comment: Nice @SQLzim  I stand corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @fromdate date = '20170101'
declare @thrudate date = '20170105'
declare @from_UserId int = 1;
declare @thru_UserId int = 3;
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate, @thrudate)+1) 
      [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
                cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
   order by [Date]
)
insert into myTable ([Date],UserId)
select [Date], u.UserId
from dates
  cross join (
    select UserId 
    from Users u
    where u.UserId >= @from_UserId
      and u.UserId <= @thru_UserId
      ) u;
```

The above uses stacked ctes to generate a numbers table, and uses that numbers table to generate dates between the date range provided.

It might not look as simple as using a `while` loop, but it will perform much better.

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/HHY62656

returns:

```
+------------+--------+
|    date    | userid |
+------------+--------+
| 2017-01-01 |      1 |
| 2017-01-02 |      1 |
| 2017-01-03 |      1 |
| 2017-01-04 |      1 |
| 2017-01-05 |      1 |
| 2017-01-01 |      2 |
| 2017-01-02 |      2 |
| 2017-01-03 |      2 |
| 2017-01-04 |      2 |
| 2017-01-05 |      2 |
| 2017-01-01 |      3 |
| 2017-01-02 |      3 |
| 2017-01-03 |      3 |
| 2017-01-04 |      3 |
| 2017-01-05 |      3 |
+------------+--------+
```

---

Number and Calendar table reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 2 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-sql/62867/)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in sql Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in sql Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

Comment: I want result be ..User (1) five days .. User (2) five days , and its on and its on whatever users i have

Comment: I dont want loop between two days only, I want between two days and ID with days , every ID has a Same days between

Comment: @MuhammadElshater I have updated my answer to include a `cross join` of a subquery that selects the `userid` from a table `users` where the `UserId` is between two values. I have also included a demo.

Comment: Thank's A lot .. it's Working :)

Comment: another question, into your code, how can I insert datename into A table with date,, i added a colum name [dateOf Name] and I Use A DATENAME Func but doesn't work !