# Database Date: How to auto increment the date automatically in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a Database called DatesOfYear

```
 CREATE TABLE DATESOFYEAR
 (
 MyName varchar(15),
 MyDate date
 );
```

and i inserted a value in it

```
 INSERT INTO DATESOFYEAR VALUES ('FName','1-JAN-2017');
```

The output is

```
 MYNAME     MYDATE
 FName      1-JAN-2017
```

How do i increment the `MyDate` from `1-JAN-2017` up until the end of year which is `31-DEC-2017`, the output that i want to see is

```
 MYNAME     MYDATE
 FName      1-JAN-2017
 ....          ....
 FName      31-DEC-2017
```

Comment: You've tagged SQL Server and MySQL. They are not one and the same. Which are you using?

Comment: Thanks, i already updated it.

Comment: So are you asking for a way to not specify a value for `date` and have it get auto incremented to the next date?

Comment: There's tonnes of questions already on Stack Overflow telling you how to generate a sequence of dates, did you try searching at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate Dates between date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824831/generate-dates-between-date-ranges)

Comment: You might as well use a dimdate table.  Google "sql dimdate script" etc.  One example is at https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/647950/Create-and-Populate-Date-Dimension-for-Data-Wareho A general query from that would be `SELECT * FROM dimdate WHERE YEAR = '2017' ORDER BY datekey`

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
DECLARE @StartDate date, @EndDate Date;
SELECT @StartDate = '20170101', @EndDate = '20171231';

WITH Dates AS(
    SELECT @StartDate AS MyDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1,MyDate)
    FROM Dates
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1,MyDate) <= @EndDate)
SELECT *
FROM Dates
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 366);
```

You can then, if you wish, `INSERT` that dataset into another table, or use it as is.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a loop and add rows in the database until you reach the end of the year. On each insert, you increment the previous date by 1 day.

```
DECLARE @my_previous_date DATE = '1-JAN-2017', 
        @my_date DATE = DATEADD(d,1, @my_previous_date);

WHILE @my_date <= '31-DEC-2017'
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO DATESOFYEAR VALUES ('FName', DATEADD(d,1, @my_date));
    @my_date = DATEADD(d,1, @my_date);
END;
```