# Fill missing rows using RECURSIVE CTE in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server-2012, missing-data, recursive-cte

Input

```
id, date, value  
1, '2020-01-01', 100  
1, '2020-01-03', 200  
1, '2020-01-05', 500
```

Output expected

```
1, '2020-01-01', 100  
1, '2020-01-02', 100  
1, '2020-01-03', 200  
1, '2020-01-04', 200  
1, '2020-01-05', 500
```

I do not want to use any calendar table joined along with this.
I want to achieve this with Recursive CTE

Comment: How about your current query ? Can you please share with us ? Also what is the logic to obtain the expected result ?

Comment: maybe this one can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7824893/3733167

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample data**

```
create table data
(
  d date,
  i int
);

insert into data (d, i) values
('2020-01-01', 100),
('2020-01-03', 200),
('2020-01-05', 500);
```

**Solution**

```
with maxDate as
(
  select max(d.d) as maxDate
  from data d
),
rcte as
(
  select d.d, d.i
  from data d
    union all
  select dateadd(day, 1, r.d), r.i
  from rcte r
  cross join maxDate md
  where r.d < md.maxDate
)
select '1' as [id],
       r.d as [date],
       max(r.i) as [value]
from rcte r
group by r.d
order by r.d;
```

**Result**

```
id  date        value
--- ----------- -----
1   2020-01-01  100
1   2020-01-02  100
1   2020-01-03  200
1   2020-01-04  200
1   2020-01-05  500
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cb568c835e8cca85d2f8713e7618884d)