# Getting individual dates from a date range using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have been asked to create two datasets showing 7 days of dates from a two date range.

Example: I have a date range of `StartDate = 2022-12-12` and `EndDate = 2022-12-25`. I need a query to display the individual dates in between these two dates. I was told to use `DATEADD`, but cannot for the life figure this out.

Any help would be be helpful, thank you.

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 7, StartDate) AS WeekOne
```

I was expecting something like this:

```
2022-12-12
2022-12-13
2022-12-14
2022-12-15
2022-12-16
2022-12-17
2022-12-18
```

Comment: A calendar table would honestly be the best thing to use. If you don't have one, then invest the time to create one.

Comment: You can use a recursive cte to create the dates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate Dates between date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824831/generate-dates-between-date-ranges)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @InStartDate DATE='2022-12-12';
DECLARE @InStopDate DATE='2022-12-25';
WITH GEN AS
(
   SELECT @InStartDate AS Start_dated
      UNION ALL
   SELECT DATEADD(DD,1,G.Start_dated)
     FROM GEN AS G
   WHERE G.Start_dated< @InStopDate
)
SELECT G.*
FROM GEN AS G
```

You can use something like this

Answer (score 0):

You need to start by **generating a numbers table**. It needs enough rows to handle each day between your start and end dates. Something like this:

```
with Numbers as (
    select 0 as n
    union all
    select n + 1
    from Numbers
    where n < 365
)
select n
from Numbers
option(maxrecursion 0);
```

Given the example range, I felt like 365 days (one year) was adequate, but it's easy to tweak that range (as we'll see).

Once you have the Numbers table, you can use `DateAdd()` to add that amount to the start date:

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '20221212'; 

with Numbers as (
    select 0 as n
    union all
    select n + 1
    from Numbers
    where n < 365
)
select DATEADD(day, n, @StartDate)
from Numbers
option(maxrecursion 0)
```

From here it's a simple matter to use the `EndDate` in a `WHERE` clause to limit the total rows:

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '20221212'; 
DECLARE @EndDate date = '20221231';

with Numbers as (
    select 0 as n
    union all
    select n + 1
    from Numbers
    where n < DATEDIFF(day, @StartDate, @EndDate)
)
select DATEADD(day, n, @StartDate)
from Numbers
option(maxrecursion 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2022 and later you can use [`Generate_Series`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/generate-series-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
declare @StartDate as Date = '20221212', @EndDate as Date = '20221225';
select DateAdd( day, Value, @StartDate ) as TargetDate
  from Generate_Series( 0, DateDiff( day, @StartDate, @EndDate ) );
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-ntrSapo).